# How to draw graph according to counter with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graph, counter

How to draw graph like below image depending on counter?
I tried [this](https://flutterawesome.com/a-beautiful-bezier-line-chart-widget-for-flutter/) tutorial but unable to understand.

Is there any package to draw a graph like this?

[image]

my code:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("CHECK-INS", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
            Text("72",style:TextStyle(fontSize: 25))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
        color: Colors.blue,
         child: //Here want to draw graph
      )
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [flutter_sparkline](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sparkline#-installing-tab-),
First declare `data` which have all co-ordinates and pass it to `Sparkline`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sparkline/flutter_sparkline.dart';

void main() {
  var data = [0.0, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, -0.5, -1.0, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0];
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new Center(
          child: new Container(
            width: 300.0,
            height: 100.0,
            child: new Sparkline(
              data: data,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Output

[image]